# Future Tense Help

Tags: future

I said: "Should I not receive my letter by the end of this week, I will pay for my bill."

I believe it should be "should" because I am talking about something that should happen in the past in the future in order to pay my bill...

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a proofreading service; however, we can help you work through specific questions about grammar or usage. For example, it would help if you indicated *why* you believe this expression may not be correct, and what research you have attempted already. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: Use of *should* here is a ok, but a little stiff/dated.  Most people nowadays would say, *"If I don't receive my letter by the end of the week, I will pay my bill."*

Comment: *Should* in this case just means *if*. As any dictionary will tell you. Why are you dragging future tense into this? English does not even have a future tense. And *should* is the *past* tense of *shall*. The question makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your use is a perfectly legitimate, if frequently disparaged and commonly avoided, first conditional subject-auxiliary inversion ("Should I") expressing the subjunctive mood in English, where the present tense ("receive") is used with a future meaning in a predictive conditional sentence. See the discussion of [subject-auxilliary inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Inversion_in_condition_clauses) in Wikipedia, and the preceding discussion of [first conditionals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#First_conditional) (op. cit.) for more information.